# Precompile assets not load in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

My Rails app is not loading assets correctly in the staging environment, even after I run rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV="staging".

This is my staging config:

```
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  # config.assets.debug = false

  config.log_level = :debug
```

[Here's a screenshot of my browser's development console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr4Yx.png).

The path is wrong... does someone know whyyy???

Comment: why did you set `config.assets.compile = false`?

Comment: Are you using this host (192.168.0.71) as your staging URL? If not, do you have access to this host from your machine?

Answer (score 0):

you tried to set up `config.assets.compile` variable to `false`? In most of cases this is the main problem! I expect help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. After migrate the Rails 3 to 4 i forgot put this config in initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( some.js some.css )
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score -1):

Configure `config.action_controller.asset_host`

Comment: The host are right.... is http://192.168.0.71:3050. The problem is the folder stylesheets was be assets.